# 5 mA low dropout voltage, current source

Tags: constant-current, low-voltage

I want to power two signal LEDs in series, about 3 V in total from a 3.3 V supply.  The on current is 5 mA and I can switch either the positive or negative rail.

Using only a resistor will not be good since the volt drop over the resistor is only 0.3 V.

Any good ideas using only one or two components.

Comment: How much voltage does your switch drop?

Comment: And how much variation in the supply voltage do you need to be able to tolerate?

Comment: why is a resistor no good? You don't say that, but of course a resistor can be used flawlessly to drop 0.3 V.

Comment: You could use a buck or buck-boost converter (depending if you need to deal with 10% variation or not), but that would be a lot more trouble than just wiring your LEDs in parallel instead of series and using resistive current limiting.

Comment: @ThePhoton Good ideas. If LED intensity is *really* important, use a separate series resistor for each LED. If your 3.3v supply is very well-regulated, and LED intensity isn't *that* important, do as Marcus has suggested. Be aware that your I/O pin has inherent series resistance (perhaps 30 ohms) that adds to the external series resistor.

Comment: With your edit, it becomes even more obvious that you forgot to actually **tell** us what the variation of voltage are.

Comment: And if you're using an IR LED for (free-space? fiber-optic?) signalling, tell us what the switching frequency is. In the original version, I assumed that "signal LED" meant a visual indicator LED, which wouldn't need to switch more than 20 Hz.

Comment: Voting to close because the details dribbling out one by one make it clear you're not giving us enough information to give you a useful answer.

Comment: Yes, please give as much information as thinkably useful, not a slow "slice-wise" taste of the metaphorical info salami. We're here to *help* you, not to *guess your application*.

Comment: I think the question looks decent now, but I came in late in the game. :)

Comment: @pipe, The supply variation still hasn't been given.

Answer (score 2):

why is a resistor no good? You don't say that, but of course a resistor can be used flawlessly to drop 0.3 V. So, I claim that is a misunderstanding on your side.

For your 5 mA current, that would be a 60 Ω resistor. If your 3.3 V comes from a regulated supply, that would work beautifully.

68 Ω is a commonly used value (a "preferred number" in the famous E-series), and would probably not yield a visible difference in brightness compared to a 60 Ω resistor.

**EDIT**: You're using the LED for IR signalling, so that *very* likely means absolute brightness doesn't matter at all as long as it doesn't change overly fast (> 10 kHz, probably). So, really, unless you've got an **extremely** unstable voltage source (which I somehow doubt), this won't matter, and even if you had, you could add a capacitor to smoothen out these variations reasonably well.

IR-based (non-fiber) devices usually use something like a 38 kHz carrier being switched on and off at low rates. There's absolutely zero need for intensity fine control here. As you say yourself – that LED is switched, so the only important difference to the signal is whether it's "on" or "off": 10% give or take in intensity really won't even remotely theoretically matter.

**EDIT**: You're still dribbling information. In this case,  baud rate 300 baud to 19.2 kbaud. So yeah, you don't care about fluctuations *slower* than 150 Hz (because your receiver will have a very easy time dealing with those, anyway) and above 38.4 kHz (since they'll be above your observable bandwidth, anyway, unless you don't design your sensor's filter sufficiently well).

So, only power supply fluctuations between roughly 0.15 and 40 kHz matter at all. You can filter these out with a 150 Hz low pass filter, eg an RC filter. Since you'll need a 60 Ω resistor in series with your LEDs anyway, that leaves the capacitor as design parameter. Electrolytic capacitors are cheap these days, so, hm, go for a 47 uF @ 10V one, and be set.

Comment: If the voltage source might drop to 3.0 V for several seconds, say due to extra current draw from another load, you'd need more than just a capacitor to fix it up.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'd argue that depends on the cap :) (let's build a 60 Ω / 470 uF RC LPF – that'd have cutoff f = 5 Hz, or so), but yeah. However, without better knowledge, I'd *wildly* guess that the 3.3V is the same that drives the MCU, and that will probably not be happy about such variations in the first place. That would be a clear case of "don't fix the consumer, fix the supply".

Comment: There's a lot of MCU's that can operate from 1.8 to 3.3 V, for example. A drop from 3.3 to 3.0 wouldn't cause much trouble for one of them. (I've done one project where I ran an MCU + LEDs off a current limited supply that was originally intended to drive the LEDs directly)

Comment: @ThePhoton that's true. But then again, seriously, are we still guessing OP's system?

Answer (score 2):

Stacking two LEDS does not buy you much headroom bearing in mind the potential LED forward voltage variance.

The circuit below will drive your LEDS in constant current mode, however, actual current is dependent on component characteristics, specifically, forward voltages. Significant variance between builds can be expected. If the variance is outside your tolerance limit you could adjust or select on test R1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBC1uH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I probably would just bite the bullet on current and put the LEDs in parallel with their own resistors.

Or buy a brighter single LED.

Comment: This simply won't work at 3.3 V. I know of no LEDs with a Vf much less than 2.2 V and most chemistries are in the 2.8 - 3.2 V range.

Comment: @JackCreasey most IR LEDS in by book are 1.5V

Comment: I think the idea is one LED is IR for signalling and the other is visible for visual indication. But it's hard to tell.

Comment: @ThePhoton, yup that could be , in which case he really needs to go parallel. I also think he got his current wrong.. most I see are rated at 50mA.

Comment: My apologies @Trevor. I do see a some IR LEDS at 1.2 - 1.5 V. But as pointed out an IR in series with a visible is still not going to work anyway. Using a transistor with a saturation voltage 0.2 V  and the voltage over the 39 Ohm resistor is about 0.2 V so you lose 0.4 V just there. It's always best to drive using a FET rather than BJT IMO.

Comment: @JackCreasey I agree, resistor or FET, no headroom left for BJT.

Comment: @JackCreasey, running at 5mA, Vf is much less though. Running IRs at that level will be fine with this circuit. Though a FET circuit might be better, why not post your answer...

Comment: Ah, by the way, ONSemi sells "diode-shaped" devices (2-terminal) that are really nothing but a cleverly self-biasing transistor to form a constant current sink over a laaaarge current range. [NSI450XX](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NSI45020), XX = current in mA

Comment: @MarcusMüller, cool nice find, I found some of those in and they were mil-spec and expensive, Pity they don't make one in 5ma, 15 seems the min.