# Protecting microcontroller from drastic changes in load on power source

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, batteries, lithium-ion, led-strip

Is it necessary to protect the VIN pin of a microcontroller (currently arduino micro) when another device on the same power source is switching between 90W and 0W? Specifically, 300 LEDs are strobing, drawing ~18A from li-ion 18650s when on. Might the batteries continue to "push" that much current for a brief period in a way that could damage the microcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That all depends on your circuitry.

However, as a general rule you would NOT put your load on the same circuit as the logic of your controller. Driving 18A through your power and ground traces shared by the controller can induce significant problems for the micro including shutting it down or resetting it.

The logic section should have it's own connection from the battery through whatever regulator you are using. If you are not using a regulator, then at least a small in-line inductor and decent bulk capacitance should feed the logic.

The LEDS should NOT be powered from the regulator, they should be direct from the battery and driven with simple constant current drivers if need be.

Similarly, the return ground should be separate and connected together as close to the battery as possible, if not at the battery itself.

BTW: The only way you could get a PUSH effect is if there is a sizeable amount of inductance in the power path from the battery to your power line. Since you have not indicated what you are using for power conditioning, it is impossible to comment if that will indeed be a factor here.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, that makes sense with the inductance and push effect. I'm using a 7805 regulator leading into the microcontroller, but may remove it in the future when I put my batteries in series. If I'm understanding the rest, I should be ok to use the same power source for everything, provided the controller and 7805 aren't sharing the same traces as the load? I should be able to keep the wiring separate and only connect them very close to the battery terminals.

Comment: @BrianFaires, The LEDS should not be powered from the regulator, they should be direct from the battery and driven with a simple constant current driver.

Comment: thanks again, time for me to go learn about constant current drivers... the rabbit hole continues.

Comment: :) I posted a simple 5mA one yesterday here.. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294120/5-ma-low-dropout-voltage-current-source/294133?noredirect=1#comment675063_294133 THough that is intended for two infra-red leds, so may not fit. You don't have to go constant current if you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Lets talk Vdd and GND networks; do not share high-current high-spark-spikes lines with circuitry (MCU or analog or radios or datalines); if you have sensitive/lownoise circuits (I don't count MCU in that class), run the sensitive circuits off the MCU raw-supply just so you get away from the low-repletion-rate high-energy motor transients. I know MCUs are noisy, but MCUs do not use 10 amp ON/OFF like motors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnmlch.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>